# Android custom home button

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to provide a custom Image and handler for the home button, which is the left button in the action bar having the application icon?

Answer (score 1):

The application icon and the home button are 2 different images.

**The application icon** can be set directly in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    ...>
```

And the home icon or the **up indicator** (as it's really called), can be changed by using overriding `homeAsUpIndicator` in your custom style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/some_up_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Of course you will need to use the custom theme for your specific Activities or the whole application (again in your manifest `activity`/`application` tags:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```